# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'days' [Odoo 15]

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I'm getting this error when I try to delete a reservation. I can't understand why, please help <3

Here is my code

```
class HotelReservationLine(models.Model):
    
    checkin = fields.Datetime(string="Checkin", related='line_id.checkin')
    checkout = fields.Datetime(string="Checkout", related='line_id.checkout')
    days = fields.Integer(string="Days", compute='_calculate_days')
    
    @api.depends('checkin', 'checkout')
    def _calculate_days(self):
        for rec in self:
            date = rec.checkout - rec.checkin
            rec.days = date.days
```

This is the traceback

> RPC_ERROR Odoo Server Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line
> 237, in _dispatch
> result = request.dispatch()   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 687, in dispatch
> result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
> return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
> return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 348, in checked_call
> result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 916, in **call**
> return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 535, in response_wrap
> response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/auto/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1343, in call_kw
> return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/auto/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1335, in
> _call_kw
> return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 464, in call_kw
> result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 451, in _call_kw_multi
> result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/auto/addons/hotel_reservation/models/hotel_reservation.py",
> line 211, in unlink
> return super(HotelReservation, self).unlink()   File "/opt/odoo/auto/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 338, in
> unlink
> res = super(MailThread, self).unlink()   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3700, in unlink
> self.flush()   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 5644, in flush
> self.recompute()   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 6117, in recompute
> process(field)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 6101, in process
> field.recompute(recs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1243, in recompute
> self.compute_value(recs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1265, in
> compute_value
> records._compute_field_value(self)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4255, in
> _compute_field_value
> getattr(self, field.compute)()   File "/opt/odoo/auto/addons/hotel_reservation/models/hotel_reservation.py",
> line 592, in _calculate_days
> rec.days = date.days Exception
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 643, in
> _handle_exception
> return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 301, in
> _handle_exception
> raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'days'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the value of `checkin` and `checkout` is not set the `rec.checkout - rec.checkin` expression is evaluated to `0` (False - False) and when Odoo tries to get `days` from `date`, it fails because `date` in this case is an integer.

It seems like Odoo triggered the compute method after it sets the checkin and checkout field values to `False`

To fix that, compute the difference in days only if the two dates are set

***Example:***

```
@api.depends('checkin', 'checkout')
def _calculate_days(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.checkin and rec.checkout:
            date = rec.checkout - rec.checkin
            rec.days = date.days
        else:
            rec.days = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you are using for loop along with self, but try below logic and let me know:

```
class HotelReservationLine(models.Model):
    
    checkin = fields.Datetime(string="Checkin", related='line_id.checkin')
    checkout = fields.Datetime(string="Checkout", related='line_id.checkout')
    days = fields.Integer(string="Days", compute='_calculate_days')
    
    @api.depends('checkin', 'checkout')
    def _calculate_days(self):
        date = self.checkout - self.checkin
        self.days = date.days
```

Comment: Because `self` is an iterable. Why should your solution change anything?

Comment: because `self` is an iterable and to be more specific it represents all records in a specific module, for example, if your module is `sale.order` then `self` refers to all orders (records) in that module

Answer (score 0):

In your code, *date* variable gets integer value, not datetime timedelta type value. So you cannot access *.days*

Try with following code:

```
@api.depends('checkin', 'checkout')
def _calculate_days(self):
    for rec in self:
        diff_days = 0
        if rec.checkout and rec.checkin:
            diff_days = (rec.checkout.date() - rec.checkin.date()).days
        rec.days = diff_days
```

[image]

**EDIT**

My local development screenshot:

- I take the date value from the datetime value.
- Subtract two date values and get days using the .days variable
- It will return days. If you use datetime value in the subtraction, you will get different days compared to date value subtraction.

[image]

Comment: Hello Bhavesh, thank you for answering! I tryed but still doesn't work. I used your code and i add a **print(type(rec.days))** and the result is **<class 'int'>**

But when I tried to delete the register, It still giving me the same traceback. I've already updated the module and no change. >>>>>>>  **File "/opt/odoo/auto/addons/hotel_reservation/models/hotel_reservation.py", line 591, in _calculate_days
    rec.days = (rec.checkout - rec.checkin).days
Exception**

Comment: I have tested my answered code and it is working fine. May be in your case, check in and check out fields are related field. [ Updated answer with if condition (check in & out)
can you add full traceback? like what is after Exception?

Comment: After Excepcion is the same traceback that I posted -> **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'days'**. The code works perfectly, but this is the traceback when I try to delete the entire reservation

Comment: Then you should ask different question with your latest code and latest trackback.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, as you are iterating through `self` it seems that there are some empty records in your module but still, the `_calculate_days` method will be triggered to compute the value of days.

For example,  `select *` on the table will give the following result:

[image]

In the screenshot above, the record that is causing the issue is `id=4`

What you should do is perform a select query in `psql` to define the records with the issue

```
select * from hotel_reservation where checkin is null or checkout is null;
```

so once you define them and you are sure about deleting them, simply you can perform a delete query on the table.

To avoid such a situation, make sure to add a default value for the fields you are using in depends decorator: `default=fields.Datetime.now()`